# In-Memory OLTP Non-Durable

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

I created In-Memory OLTP Non-Durable Tables in 4 different  SQL servers.Lately one of the server performance has degraded and  I see lot of processes (Almost 200-300) running with command XTP THREAD_POOL.I don't see any such processes running on other 3 servers and there isn't any performance issues on them either.

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Curious if all servers are the same patch level.

Comment: I was running batch and it completed in 4 hours with physical tables and took me 4hrs 30mins with in-memory tables.As i mentioned earlier I dont see such issue with other 3 servers and I dont see such process either.I have output for your query but how can i attach that file?

Comment: @RandolphWest added picture to question.Let me know if you need more fields. Thanks

Comment: Nothing exciting there. I'm going to clean up my comments above, and ask for you to have a look at Windows Performance Monitor for the XTP storage counters to look for any correlation there. Important to remember that disk I/O still happens irrespective of your durability settings. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-xtp-storage

Comment: Sure I will check that.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RandolphWest - not sure how the link you supplied relates to disk I/O for memory-optimized tables that are schema-only. Other than file pre-creation, I would expect 0 disk I/O.

Comment: Ruling out the obvious, because assumptions are bad. If the counters do indeed show zero I/O, then look elsewhere. The DMV output showed minimal I/O, so it’s increased confidence that it’s something else. Now I just want to make sure. We also don’t know if they’re all at the same patch level like you asked, or indeed which version or edition this is.